# Google Contacts - feed etag?

Tags: google-contacts-api, etag

When accessing the Google Contacts api, I would like to be able to determine if anything has changed, so that I don't try to download contacts if nothing has. According to the documentation, the feed tag should look something like:

```
<feed xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'
      xmlns:openSearch='http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/'
      xmlns:gContact='http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008'
      xmlns:batch='http://schemas.google.com/gdata/batch'
      xmlns:gd='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'
      gd:etag='feedEtag'>
```

but when I query for my contacts, I see:

```
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" 
      xmlns:batch="http://schemas.google.com/gdata/batch" 
      xmlns:gContact="http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008" 
      xmlns:gd="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005" 
      xmlns:openSearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/">
```

No etag in site. That's ok, I'll use the "updated" value, right? Except that seems to change
every time I make a request. So it's not really "updated", it's "accessed". Any suggestions?

My basic request looks something like:

```
curl -s --header "Content-Type: text/xml" \
        --header "Depth: 1" \
        --header "Authorization: Bearer <my token>" \
        https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full/
```

Do I need to add something to get the etag back?

Comment: Did you specify the version number in your request?? Every request that you send using the Google Contacts API should specify version 3.0 of the API.

To specify a version number, use the GData-Version HTTP header:

GData-Version: 3.0. Here is the link for the documentation https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#specifying_a_version.

Comment: I got that in another thread. I missed that, building from the examples. Thanks.